# Saving user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I buy and sell products and I want to make a program that saves me time.
When I buy these fixed products I want to save time by making a program that asks me "how many of x product" and then "product y" and so on.
At the end I want it to print how many products I have in total and whats their dollar value.

Also between questions I want it to print the total in dollars for that product. For example, #INPUT "How many product X" 10  #OUTPUT: "You have 10 product X worth 100 dollars."

Then at the end i want python to add up x, y, z and print"You have X amount of products worth 300 dollars in total"

This is what I've came up with so far.

```
 product1 = 20
 product2 = 12
 product3 = 20
 product4 = 25
 product5 = 25
 product6 = 17
 product7 = 19
 product8 = 19
 product9 = 17
 product10 = 25
 product11 = 5
 product12 = 5
 product13 = 5
 product14 = 20
 product15 = 24

def timesaver():
    product1_amount = int(input("How many product1? "))
    print(f"You have {product1_amount} product1 and  {product1_amount * product1} Dollars worth\n\n")
    product1_total =  product1_amount 
    product1_dollars = product1_amount * product1
    print('\n\n')
```

I repeat this over and over to get the job done the code sucks and its not efficient at all. any help?

I've also made some loops that ask the questions like this, putting all products into a list with no price attached.

But how do I save each user input into a different variables so I can perform operations on each one?

```
for index in products:
    question = int(input("How many " + str(index) + " ?"))
```

Comment: If it were me, at the beginning I'd do it in Excel.

Comment: @user1443098: Just edit the typo. No need to leave extraneous comments.

Answer (score 2):

Make a dictionary of products to prices.  Then loop over that dictionary to ask how many of a particular product the user wants.  Use that data to build a second dictionary representing the order itself.

```
products = {
    "apple": 1.00,
    "pear": .70,
    "banana": .10,
    "kiwi": 1.50,
    "melon": 5.75,
    "pineapple": 12.0,
}


def get_order():
    order = {}
    for product, price in products.items():
        amount = int(input(f"How many {product} do you want at {price:.2f} each?"))
        order[product] = (price, amount)
    print("Your total is {:.2f}".format(sum(x*y for x, y in order.values())))
    return order
```

Comment: This is certainly a better answer than mine if OP wants to have names associated with their products.

Answer (score 1):

Consider storing your product prices into an array:

```
products = [20, 12, 30, 25, 25, 17, 19, 19, 17, 25, 5, 5, 5, 20, 24]
def timesaver() :
    productNumber = 1
    totals = []
    dollars = []
    for product in products :
        amount = int(intput("How many product{}? ".format(productNumber))
        print(f"You have {amount} product{productNumber} and {amount * product} Dollars worth\n\n")
        totals.append(amount)
        dollars.append(amount * product)
        print('\n\n')
     print(totals)
     print(dollars)
```

Now you still have all of the same values saved,

For example: `product1_total` = `totals[0]`, `product2_total` = `totals[1]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of a function is a good start

You may want to consider using a `dictionary`. It allows you to do lookups by name, and they are a constant time process, meaning that no matter how many products you have, the lookup time is the same.

This can be done like so:

```
products = {'product1_name': 20, 'product2_name': 12, ..., 'productn_name': 300}
```

With this in mind, you could do the following with your function:

```
def timesaver(product, amount):
    # Product is the name of the product you want
    val = products[product]

    # Amount is an integer value
    total = amount * val

    print("Total for product {0}: {1}".format(product, total))
```

The total use could be in a while-loop using the `input` function you wanted:

```
for product in products.keys():
    amt = int(input("How many of {}?  ".format(product)))
    timesaver(product, amt)
```